# C++ Template Linked List storing Class Objects - Unhandled Exception Access Violation Reading Location

Tags: c++, class, templates, exception, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a template linked list into a project I'm working on with a lot of classes. It works a bit like a map or set where there is key data and value data. I created it and tested it in a seperate project using ints and string values, and all the functions work inside it work, I even got it to work with serialization using the BOOST libraries.

This is the entire class file for my list:

```
#ifndef LINKED_LIST_H
#define LINKED_LIST_H

#include <boost\serialization\access.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<typename Tkey, typename Tvalue>
class Node
{
public:
Tkey keyData;
Tvalue valueData;
Node * next;
Node()
{   
    next = NULL;
}
Node(Tkey x, Tvalue y)
{
    keyData = x;
    valueData = y;
    next = NULL;
}
Node(Tkey x, Tvalue y, Node * z)
{
    keyData = x;
    valueData = y;
    next = z;
}

template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar & keyData;
    ar & valueData;
    ar & next;
}
};

template<typename Tkey, typename Tvalue>
class LinkedList
{
Node<Tkey, Tvalue> *head;
int count;
public:
LinkedList()
{
    head = NULL;
    count = 0;
}
~LinkedList()
{
    Clear();
}

template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar & head;
    ar & count;
}

int Size()
{
    return count;
}

bool Empty()
{
    return (count == 0);
}

bool Add(Tkey key, Tvalue value)
{
    Node<Tkey, Tvalue> *p;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = new Node<Tkey, Tvalue> (key, value, NULL);
        count++;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        p = head;
        while(p->next !=NULL)
            p=p->next;
        p->next = new Node<Tkey, Tvalue> (key, value, NULL);
        count++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool Remove(Tkey key)
{
    Node<Tkey, Tvalue> *p;

    if (head->keyData == key)
    {
        head = head->next;
        return true;
    }

    p=head;

    while (p->next->keyData != key && p->next->next != NULL)
    {
        p = p->next;
    }

    if (p->next->keyData == key && p->next != NULL)
    {
        Node<Tkey, Tvalue> *temp;
        temp = p->next;
        p->next = temp->next;
        count--;
        delete temp;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

Tvalue Get(Tkey key)
{
    Node<Tkey, Tvalue> *p;

    p = head;

    while (p->next != NULL)
    {
        if (p->keyData == key)
        {
            return p->valueData;
        }
        p = p->next;
    }

    return NULL;
}

Tvalue Find(int i)
{
    int selection = 0;

    Node<Tkey, Tvalue> *p;

    p = head;

    while (selection != i && p->next != NULL)
    {
        p = p->next;
        selection++;
    }

    if (p->next == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return p->valueData;
}

Tkey Exists (Tvalue value)
{
    Node<Tkey, Tvalue> *p;

    p = head;

    while (p->next != NULL)
    {
        if (p->valueData == value)
        {
            return p->keyData;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

void Clear()
{
    Node<Tkey,Tvalue> * temp;
    while (head != 0)
    {
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        count--;
        delete temp;
    }
}

void Print(Tkey key)
{
    Node<Tkey, Tvalue> * p;
    p = head;
    while(p->keyData != key && p->next != NULL)
    {
        p = p->next;
    }

    if (p->keyData == key && p->next != NULL)
    {
        cout << p->keyData << " " << p->valueData << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Data not found" << endl;
    }
}

void PrintAll()
{
    Node<Tkey, Tvalue> * p;
    p = head;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        cout << p->keyData << " " << p->valueData << "\n";
        p = p->next;
    }
}
};
#endif
```

To test it out in my project, I created a Linked List variable with an int and one of my classes, then tried to add and get the value data to modify a value.

```
LinkedList<int,Customer *> customerList;
customerList.Add(1, new Customer("Jack Smith", "1 Adelade Road", "5678", "Male", 4,8,1999));
customerList.Get(1)->AddAccount("9081", new JuniorCurrentAccount("100126764", 50, 25,12,2010));
```

However when I run it I get an unhandled exception at the Add method pointing at 
    if(head == NULL)

The exception says "Access violation reading location"

So far I have tried changing the NULLs to 0s when the list checks for Nodes but that didn't stop the exception, I have also tried including the headers for the class files but that caused a lot of errors that involving accessing variables within those classes.

I believe something is wrong within the class itself, but I cannot find what is causing it. As I said, this class works fine with basic data types (ints, strings ect) but classes is what is causing the errors. Any help would be greatful!

EDIT: Here is the code for the Customer Class .cpp file
    #include "Customer.h"
    #include "Account.h"
    #include "CorportateSavings.h"
    #include "CurrentAccount.h"
    #include "JuniorCurrentAccount.h"
    #include "StudentSavings.h"
    #include "Mortgage.h"
    #include "BuyToLetMortgage.h"
    #include "DiscountMortgage.h"
    #include "FixedRateMortgage.h"
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include

```
using namespace std;

Customer::Customer(string Name, string Address, string TelephoneNo, string Gender, int DOBday, int DOBmonth, int DOByear) : name(Name), address(Address), telephoneNo(TelephoneNo), gender(Gender), DOB(DOBday,DOBmonth,DOByear)
{
parent = 0;
}

Customer::Customer(string Name, string Address, string TelephoneNo, string Gender, int DOBday, int DOBmonth, int DOByear, Customer *c) : name(Name), address(Address), telephoneNo(TelephoneNo), gender(Gender), DOB(DOBday,DOBmonth,DOByear)
{
parent = c;
}

Customer::~Customer(void)
{

}

void Customer::printDetails()
{
//Prints out details of customer
cout << "Name       : " << name << endl;
cout << "Address        : " << address << endl;
cout << "Telephone No   : " << telephoneNo << endl;
cout << "Gender     : " << gender << endl;
cout << "Date of Birth  : ";
printStringDOB();
//If customer has a registered parent/guardian
if (parent != 0)
    cout << "Parent/Guardian Name: " << parent->getName() << endl;

cout << endl;
}

string Customer::getName()
{
return name;
}

void Customer::setName(string Name)
{
name = Name;
}

string Customer::getAddress()
{
return address;
}

void Customer::setAddress(string Address)
{
address = Address;
}

string Customer::getTelephoneNo()
{
return telephoneNo;
}

void Customer::setTelephoneNo(string TelephoneNo)
{
telephoneNo = TelephoneNo;
}

string Customer::getGender()
{
return gender;
}

void Customer::setGender(string Gender)
{
gender = Gender;
}

void Customer::printStringDOB()
{
DOB.printString(); 
}

double Customer::getDOB()
{
return DOB.juldays();
}

void Customer::setDOB(int day, int month, int year)
{
DOB.setDay(day);
DOB.setMonth(month);
    DOB.setYear(year);
}

int Customer::getAge(int Day, int Month, int Year)
{
return DOB.DifferenceYear(Day, Month, Year);
}

void Customer::setParent(Customer * c)
{
parent = c;
}

Customer * Customer::getParent()
{
if (parent = 0)
{
    return NULL;
}
else
{
    return parent;
}
}

void Customer::AccountManager()
{
int choice = AccountManagerChooser();
cout << endl;

while (choice != 9)
{
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        //Create a bank acount
        CreateAccountManager();
        choice = AccountManagerChooser();
        break;
    case 2:
        {
            //Use a bank account
            string pin;

            cout << "Enter PIN: ";
            cin >> pin;

            UseAccount(pin);
            choice = AccountManagerChooser();
            break;
        }
    case 3:
        {
            //Remove a bank account
            char yn;
            cout << "Enter PIN: ";
            string pin;
            cin >> pin;
            if (accountList.Get(pin) != NULL)
            {
                cout << "Are you sure? (Y/N) ";
                cin >> yn;
                if (yn == 'y' || yn == 'Y')
                {
                    accountList.Remove(pin);
                    cout << "Account Removed Successfully" << endl;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Invalid PIN or Account does not exist" << endl;
            }
            choice = AccountManagerChooser();
            break;
        }
    case 4:
        //Print Customer Details
        printDetails();
        choice = 0;
        break;
    case 5:
        {
            //Change Customer Details
            int detailChange = 0;

            while (detailChange != -1)
            {
                cout << "1 Name" << endl;
                cout << "2 Address" << endl;
                cout << "3 Telephone No" << endl;
                cout << "4 Gender" << endl;
                cout << "5 Date of Birth" << endl;
                cout << "Which piece of detail do you want to change? ";
                cin >> detailChange;
                string str;
                getline(cin, str);
                cout << endl;

                switch (detailChange)
                {
                case 1:
                    {
                        string newName;
                        cout << "Enter new name: ";
                        getline(cin, newName);
                        setName(newName);
                        break;
                    }

                case 2:
                    {
                        string newAddress;
                        cout << "Enter new Address: ";
                        getline (cin,newAddress);
                        setAddress(newAddress);
                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    {
                        string newTelephone;
                        cout << "Enter new Telephone Number: ";
                        getline (cin,newTelephone);
                        setTelephoneNo(newTelephone);
                        break;
                    }
                case 4:
                    {
                        string newGender;
                        cout << "Enter Gender" << endl;
                        getline (cin,newGender);
                        gender = newGender;
                        break;
                    }
                case 5:
                    int newDay = 0;
                    int newMonth = 0;
                    int newYear = 0;
                    cout << "Enter Day: ";
                    cin >> newDay;
                    cout << "Enter Month: ";
                    cin >> newMonth;
                    cout << "Enter Year: ";
                    cin >> newYear;

                    setDOB(newDay,newMonth,newYear);
                    break;
                }

                char yn = 0;
                cout << "Would you like to change anything else? (Y/N) ";
                cin >> yn;

                if (yn == 'Y' || yn == 'y')
                {
                    detailChange = 0;
                    cout << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    detailChange = -1;
                    cout << endl;
                }
            }
            choice = AccountManagerChooser();
            cout << endl;
        }
        break;
    case 6:
        //Create a mortgage
        {
            time_t t = time(0);
            struct tm * now = localtime( & t );

            CreateMortgageManager();

            choice = AccountManagerChooser();
            cout << endl;
        }
        break;

    case 7:
        //Use a mortgage
        {
            string str;
            string pin;
            getline(cin,str);
            cout << "Enter PIN: ";
            getline(cin,pin);
            UseMortgage(pin);
            choice = AccountManagerChooser();
            cout << endl;
        }
        break;

    case 8:
        //Remove a mortgage
        {
            string str;
            string pin;
            getline(cin,str);
            cout << "Enter PIN: ";
            getline(cin,pin);
            RemoveMortgage(pin);
            choice = AccountManagerChooser();
            cout << endl;
        }
        break;
    case 9:
        break;
    default:
        cout << endl;
        choice = AccountManagerChooser();
        break;
    }

    if (choice == 9)
    {
        cout << "Thank you for your time!\n\n" << endl;
    }
    else if (choice == 0)
    {
        choice = AccountManagerChooser();
    }
}
}

int Customer::AccountManagerChooser()
{
cout << "What would you like to do?" << endl;
cout << "1: Create a new account" << endl;
cout << "2: Use an account" << endl;
cout << "3: Close an account" << endl;
cout << "4: Show Personal Details" << endl;
cout << "5: Update Personal Details" << endl;
cout << "6: Create a Mortgage" << endl;
cout << "7: Use a Mortgage" << endl;
cout << "8: Remove a Mortgage" << endl;
cout << "9: Exit" << endl;
cout << "Enter Choice: ";
int choice;
cin >> choice;
cout << endl;
return choice;
}

void Customer::CreateAccountManager()
{
int choice = 0;

while (choice != -1)
{
    time_t t = time(0);
    struct tm * now = localtime( & t );

    cout << "What account do you wish to create?" << endl;
    cout << "1: Corporate Savings" << endl;
    cout << "2: Current Account" << endl;
    cout << "3: Junior Account" << endl;
    cout << "4: Student Savings Account" << endl;
    cout << "5: Cancel" << endl;
    cout << "Enter Choice: ";
    cin >> choice;
    cout << endl;

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        //Corporate Savings Account Made
        //Grabs age from current date
        if (getAge(now->tm_mday, now->tm_mon + 1, now->tm_year + 1900) >= 16)
        {
            cout << "Please enter how much you wish to deposit: ";
            double initDeposit;
            cin >> initDeposit;

            cout << "Please enter a four digit number to set as the PIN: ";
            string PIN;
            cin >> PIN;

            cout << "Please enter a 9 digit number to set as the account number: ";
            string AccountNo;
            cin >> AccountNo;

            AddAccount(PIN, new CorporateSavings(AccountNo, initDeposit, now->tm_mday, now->tm_mon + 1, now->tm_year + 1900));
            cout << "Corporate Savings Account Created" << endl;
            choice = -1;
        }
        else if (getAge(now->tm_mday, now->tm_mon + 1, now->tm_year + 1900) < 16)
        {
            cout << "Corportate Savings Account is only available to customers over the age of 16" << endl;
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        //Current Account Made
        //Grabs age from current date
        if (getAge(now->tm_mday, now->tm_mon + 1, now->tm_year + 1900) >= 16)
        {
            cout << "Please enter how much you wish to deposit: ";
            double initDeposit;
            cin >> initDeposit;

            cout << "Please enter a four digit number to set as the PIN: ";
            string PIN;
            cin >> PIN;

            cout << "Please enter a 9 digit number to set as the account number: ";
            string AccountNo;
            cin >> AccountNo;

            AddAccount(PIN, new CurrentAccount(AccountNo, initDeposit, now->tm_mday, now->tm_mon + 1, now->tm_year + 1900));
            cout << "Current Account Created" << endl;
            choice = -1;
        }
        else if (getAge(now->tm_mday, now->tm_mon + 1, now->tm_year + 1900) < 16)
        {
            cout << "Current Account is only available to customers over the age of 16" << endl;
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        //Junior Current Account Made
        //Grabs age from current date
        if (getAge(now->tm_mday, now->tm_mon + 1, now->tm_year + 1900) <= 16)
        {
            cout << "Please enter how much you wish to deposit: ";
            double initDeposit;
            cin >> initDeposit;

            cout << "Please enter a four digit number to set as the PIN: ";
            string PIN;
            cin >> PIN;

            cout << "Please enter a 9 digit number to set as the account number: ";
            string AccountNo;
            cin >> AccountNo;

            AddAccount(PIN, new JuniorCurrentAccount(AccountNo, initDeposit, now->tm_mday, now->tm_mon + 1, now->tm_year + 1900));
            cout << "Junior Account Created" << endl;
            choice = -1;
        }
        else if (getAge(now->tm_mday, now->tm_mon + 1, now->tm_year + 1900) > 16)
        {
            cout << "Junior Account is only available to customers under the age of 16" << endl;
        }
        else if (parent != 0)
        {
            cout << "Customers applying for Junior Account must have an adult registered as a guardian" << endl;
        }

        break;
    case 4:
        //Student Savings Account Made
        //Grabs age from current date
        if (getAge(now->tm_mday, now->tm_mon + 1, now->tm_year + 1900) >= 18)
        {
            cout << "Please enter how much you wish to deposit: ";
            double initDeposit;
            cin >> initDeposit;

            cout << "Please enter a four digit number to set as the PIN: ";
            string PIN;
            cin >> PIN;

            cout << "Please enter a 9 digit number to set as the account number: ";
            string AccountNo;
            cin >> AccountNo;

            AddAccount(PIN, new StudentSavings(AccountNo, initDeposit, now->tm_mday, now->tm_mon + 1, now->tm_year + 1900));
            cout << "Student Account Created" << endl;
            choice = -1;
        }
        else if (getAge(now->tm_mday, now->tm_mon + 1, now->tm_year + 1900) < 18)
        {
            cout << "Student Account is only available to customers over the age of 18" << endl;
        }
        break;
    case 5:
        choice = -1;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Not a valid choice" << endl;
        break;
    }
}
}

void Customer::AddAccount(string PIN, Account * a)
{
accountList.Add(PIN, a);
}

bool Customer::UseAccount(string PIN)
{
if (accountList.Get(PIN) != NULL)
{
    int choice = 0;

    while (choice != -1)
    {
        cout << "What would you like to do?" << endl;
        cout << "1: Deposit Cash" << endl;
        cout << "2: Deposit Cheque" << endl;
        cout << "3: Withdraw Cash" << endl;
        cout << "4: Show Balance" << endl;
        cout << "5: Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Enter Choice: ";
        cin >> choice;
        cout << endl;

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            {
                cout << "Enter Deposit Amount: ";
                double amount;
                cin >> amount;
                if (accountList.Get(PIN)->depositAmount(amount))
                {
                    time_t t = time(0);
                    struct tm * now = localtime( & t );

                    ofstream output;
                    output.open("Transactions.txt", ios::app);
                    output << "Name: " << name << " - Account Number: " << accountList.Get(PIN)->AccountNumber() << " - Deposit: £" << 
                        amount << " - Date: " << now->tm_mday << "/" << now->tm_mon + 1 << "/" << now->tm_year + 1900 << endl;
                    output.close();
                    cout << "Amount Deposited Successfully" << endl;
                }
                else
                    cout << "Deposit Invalid" << endl;

                choice = 0;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            {
                time_t t = time(0);
                struct tm * now = localtime( & t );

                ofstream output;
                output.open("Transactions.txt", ios::app);
                output << "Name: " << name << " - Account Number: " << accountList.Get(PIN)->AccountNumber() << " - Cheque Deposit: £" 
                    << " - Date: " << now->tm_mday << "/" << now->tm_mon + 1 << "/" << now->tm_year + 1900 << endl;
                output.close();
                cout << "Amount Deposited Successfully" << endl;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            {
                cout << "Enter Withdraw Amount: ";
                double amount;
                cin >> amount;
                if (accountList.Get(PIN)->widthdrawAmount(amount))
                {
                    time_t t = time(0);
                    struct tm * now = localtime( & t );

                    ofstream output;
                    output.open("Transactions.txt", ios::app);
                    output << "Name: " << name << " - Account Number: " << accountList.Get(PIN)->AccountNumber() << " - Withdrawal: £" << 
                        amount << " - Date: " << now->tm_mday << "/" << now->tm_mon + 1 << "/" << now->tm_year + 1900 << endl;
                    output.close();
                    cout << "Amount Withdrawn Successfully" << endl;
                }
                else
                    cout << "Withdraw Invalid" << endl;

                choice = 0;
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            {
                time_t t = time(0);
                struct tm * now = localtime( & t );

                accountList.Get(PIN)->addInterest(now->tm_mday, now->tm_mon + 1, now->tm_year + 1900);

                cout << "Balance: £" << accountList.Get(PIN)->Amount() << endl;

                choice = 0;
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            choice = -1;
            break;
        default:
            choice = 0;
            break;
        }

        char yn;
        cout << "Do you want to use another service? (Y/N) ";
        cin >> yn;

        if ((yn == 'y' || yn == 'Y') && choice != -1)
        {
            choice = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            choice = -1;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
return false;
}

void Customer::RemoveAccount(string PIN)
{
char choice;

cout << "Are you sure? (Y/N): ";
cin >> choice;
cout << endl;
while (choice != 'y' || choice != 'Y' || choice != 'n' || choice != 'N')
{
    cout << "Are you sure? (Y/N): ";
    cin >> choice;
    cout << endl;
}

accountList.Remove(PIN);
}

void Customer::CreateMortgageManager()
{
//Grabs age from current date
time_t t = time(0);
struct tm * now = localtime( & t );

if (getAge(now->tm_mday, now->tm_mon + 1, now->tm_year + 1900) >= 18)
{
    int choice = 0;

    cout << "Please enter the value of your House/Apartment: ";
    double value;
    cin >> value;

    cout << "Please enter the length of the payment (years) : 1, 2 or 4" << endl;
    int length;
    cin >> length;

    cout << "Please enter the PIN number of the bank account you wish to pay installments to: ";
    string accountPIN;
    cin >> accountPIN;

    if (accountList.Get(accountPIN) == NULL)
    {
        while (accountList.Get(accountPIN) == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Account PIN not valid or Account doesn't exist\n" << endl;         
            cout << "Please enter the PIN number of the bank account you wish to pay installments to: ";
            cin >> accountPIN;
        }
    }

    while (choice != -1)
    {
        cout << "What kind of Mortgage do you wish to create?" << endl;
        cout << "1: Fixed Rate Mortgage : " << ((value*0.8)+50)/(length * 12) << " per month with 5% Interest" << endl;
        cout << "2: Discount Mortgage   : " << ((value*0.8)+80)/(length * 12) << " per month with 3.8% Interest (5% Interest after 2 years)" << endl;
        cout << "3: Buy to Let Mortgage : "  << ((value*0.8)+120)/(length * 12) << " per month with 7.35% Interest" << endl;
        cout << "4: Cancel" << endl;
        cout << "Enter Choice: ";
        cin >> choice;
        cout << endl;

        string str;
        getline(cin,str);

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            {
                cout << "Please enter a PIN, so you can access your mortgage securely: ";
                string PIN;
                getline(cin,PIN);

                AddMortgage(PIN, new FixedRateMortgage(value, 50.0, accountList.Get(accountPIN), length, now->tm_mday, now->tm_mon + 1, now->tm_year + 1900));
                cout << "Fixed Rate Mortgage Created" << endl;
                choice = -1;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            {
                cout << "Please enter a PIN, so you can access your mortgage securely: ";
                string PIN;
                getline(cin,PIN);

                AddMortgage(PIN, new DiscountMortgage(value, 45.0, accountList.Get(accountPIN), length, now->tm_mday, now->tm_mon + 1, now->tm_year + 1900));
                cout << "Discount Mortgage Created" << endl;
                choice = -1;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            {
                cout << "Please enter a PIN, so you can access your mortgage securely: ";
                string PIN;
                getline(cin,PIN);

                AddMortgage(PIN, new BuyToLetMortgage(value, 70.0, accountList.Get(accountPIN), length, now->tm_mday, now->tm_mon + 1, now->tm_year + 1900));
                cout << "Buy To Let Mortgage Created" << endl;
                choice = -1;
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            choice = -1;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Not a valid choice" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "Mortgages are only available to customers over the age of 18" << endl;
}
}

void Customer::AddMortgage(string PIN, Mortgage * m)
{
mortgageList.Add(PIN, m);
}

void Customer::UseMortgage(string PIN)
{
if (mortgageList.Get(PIN) != NULL)
{
    int choice = 0;

    while (choice != -1)
    {
        cout << "What would you like to do?" << endl;
        cout << "1: Pay Installment" << endl;
        cout << "2: Print Payment List" << endl;
        cout << "3: Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Enter Choice: ";
        cin >> choice;
        cout << endl;

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            {
                time_t t = time(0);
                struct tm * now = localtime( & t );

                mortgageList.Get(PIN)->PayInstallment(now->tm_mday, now->tm_mon + 1, now->tm_year + 1900);

                choice = 0;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            {
                mortgageList.Get(PIN)->PrintPaymentLog();
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            choice = -1;
            break;
        default:
            choice = 0;
            break;
        }

        char yn;
        cout << "Do you want to use another service? (Y/N) ";
        cin >> yn;

        if ((yn == 'y' || yn == 'Y') && choice != -1)
        {
            choice = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            choice = -1;
        }
    }
}
}

void Customer::RemoveMortgage(string PIN)
{
char choice;

cout << "Are you sure? (Y/N): ";
cin >> choice;
cout << endl;
while (choice != 'y' || choice != 'Y' || choice != 'n' || choice != 'N')
{
    cout << "Are you sure? (Y/N): ";
    cin >> choice;
    cout << endl;
}

mortgageList.Remove(PIN);
}
```

Comment: You post the code for LinkedList but your example uses DictionaryList

Comment: This normally means the something like stack overflow happened, and the stack allocated to customerList was overwritten with something else? Just a guess

Comment: Thanks for pointing that code out, I copied from the wrong project.

Comment: When I use typedef std::tuple<string,string,string,string,int,int,int> Customer; and run your code, it seems to handle the Add find. Can you post code for the Customer class.

Comment: I've just posted the Customer Class .cpp code, sorry it is very large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you have a 1-element list and you call `Get`?

```
Tvalue Get(Tkey key)
{
    Node<Tkey, Tvalue> *p;

    p = head;

    while (p->next != NULL)
    {
        if (p->keyData == key)
        {
            return p->valueData;
        }
        p = p->next;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

`p` is not NULL, but `p->next` is NULL, which means you'll never get into the body of the `while` loop.  That means you'll return NULL, and if you try to subsequently dereference that:

```
customerList.Get(1)->AddAccount("9081", new JuniorCurrentAccount("100126764", 50, 25,12,2010));
```

...then you could get an access violation.